# Invoking an exported function from module in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

The question is a simple one.

Here is how the module exports the function.

```
exports = module.exports = debug.debug = debug;
```

Here is how the ES5 module consumes it.

```
var debug = require('debug')('http')
```

Now in Typescript it's a bit different.

```
import * as debug from 'debug';
```

This returns a strange object that I have never seen before, a nested object without a key value pair.

```
{ [Function: debug]
  coerce: [Function: coerce],
  disable: [Function: disable],
  // More properties go here
}
```

**How do I invoke the function `debug`**

Comment: That first item you're seeing is indicating that the object returned is a callable. You can invoke it, e.g. `import * as debug from 'debug'; debug('http');`.

Comment: Nope that did not work.

Comment: ?? In your answer you are invoking `debug` exactly the same way I mentioned in my comment.

Comment: Yep exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found it digging through the [documentation](https://github.com/visionmedia/debug)

```
const log = debug('http');
log.log = console.log.bind(console); // binding to console
```